# alignSelf: 'stretch' in iOS vs Android (aka width:100%)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to style a component to stretch the whole width of the view. In Android this works by adding a `style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', width: null}}` in the component, however the same code on iOS does nothing. What would be a good workaround? Also any idea why they act differently?

I'm doing a button component that should work in various situations, so the idea is that the component itself should stretch (if the prop is given), instead of touching the container around it. So modifying the container's flex properties should be avoided, even though I could probably do it with something like justifyContent:stretch off the top of my head, but for this purpose let's rule this option out... Also because this is an app that is working now fine on Android and needs to be ported to iOS, so I'm trying to do as small changes as possible. I can't rewrite the entire code to work around this issues. I'd need a self-contained solution if possible...

Using RN 0.21. I know I should update but that's a headache that I'm saving for later...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try add flex:1 to your component?
If your parent have any width and your only child flex: 1, then the child should have 100% width.